# Redirecting old page

Tags: html, css, web, web-content

Whenever someone leaves my site by clicking on a link to another site on my website the link opens in a new tab on desktop or a new window on mobile. I was wondering when that new tab opens whether once there not viewing the old tab it could go onto another page automatically, like a thank you page with the social media links.

Hope that makes sense,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, have I understood your question but probably you need something like this http://jsfiddle.net/zyhrs5j4/

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:goToThanksPage()">Google</a>
```

EDIT:

Base on our comments, here is code which I made after inspect your page, and it will add on click function on each link:

```
<script>
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".feed-item a");
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    links[i].onclick = function() {
        location.href="/mypage.html";
    }
}



</script>
```

Comment: that is exactly what I'm after, thank you so much. Is there anyway i can apply this to all links on one page apart from the ones that link to other pages on my domiain

Comment: Could you share some code? Do you generate links somehow or it's hardcoded links?

Comment: what i use is a Wordpress RSS aggregator, so whenever they leave the site on one of them links [link](http://footballnewsdaily.net/arsenal/)

Comment: Hi, I have added the HTML into the Body and nothing seems to be happening any suggestions why, thanks again

Comment: do i need to add both codes you sent or the just the second one

Comment: Sorry my fault, check code in answer now. You should copy whole code in <script></script> at end of your body.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I have implemented the code at the end of the body but it's still not working, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Edited I hope the last time. :)

Comment: Just a minor note, but you don't need `javascript:` in an event handler - javascript is the only thing it can be.  You only need it when you're using javascript as the `href` attribute in an anchor (`<a href="javascript:doThis();">...</a>`)

Comment: @freefaller, thats true, thaks

Answer (score 0):

You could just have a line of JavaScript after opening a new tab for any external url to redirect page to thankYou.html or whatever its called.

You just pass the external url trough the JS and it will open a new window and redirect current page.

```
function redir(externalUrl){
    var win = window.open(externalUrl, '_blank');
    win.focus();
    window.location = "/thankYou.html";
}
```